# I Can't figure out ho to add a return to text in UITextView attributes inspector

Tags: xcode, text, return, uitextview

xCode 5.0.2

Ive got some text i want to appear in a UITextView so the user can add to it like a template.
It needs to be a list that they can add their info to it :

- Like:
- This:
- Put:
- Number:
- Beside:

I tried doing this in the Attributes inspector and manually in the storyboard.
But every time I hit return in the attributes inspector it takes it as Enter.

IS there a special character I need to use in order to get a hard return in the body of the text?

Very confused with this.

Comment: That IDE is called Xcode and you may want to try using \n or Alt+Return.

Comment: And how did you get Xcode 5.2? The latest public ix 5.1.1.

Comment: It's Shift+Enter or Maj+Enter or something like that (Ctrl+Enter?), never remember which one.

Comment: Thanks Till.  alt Return Worked. Strange thought I tried that one.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution:
To change lines in IB:
*Alt+Return*

Answer (score 0):

When using the storyboard's Text View attribute inspector on a Mac I used option + return in order to create a new line. Be aware of your font size as the spacing will be affected.

[Story board Attribute Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOr67.png)